# Looping through a Component in Vue - Custom elements in iteration require 'v-bind:key' directives

Tags: vue.js

I'm attempting to create multiple custom components (just as a proof of concept so nothing fancy just duplicating the same component 5 times) but I'm getting the following error:

> Custom elements in iteration require 'v-bind:key' directives.

Here's the code for the loop (which I'm pretty sure where the problem is:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <app-server-status v-for="server in 5"></app-server-status>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ServerStatus from './ServerStatus'

    export default {
        components: {
            'app-server-status': ServerStatus
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now from the reading up I've done I can see that I need a key somewhere due to the limitations of using a component in later versions of Vue - just not quite sure on the correct way to do it. Can some one advise me how I'd need to modify that specific example to just show the component 5 times?

Side note: The code below gives me the result I need in the app but VSCode is still giving me an error (Expected 'v-bind:key' directive to use the variables which are defined by the 'v-for' directive.):

```
<app-server-status v-for="server in 5" :key="index"></app-server-status>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>could</s> **should** be:

```
<app-server-status v-for="(server, index) in 5" v-bind:key="index"></app-server-status>
```

**update:**

according [vue](https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) documentation:

> It is recommended to provide a `key` attribute with `v-for` whenever
> possible, unless the iterated DOM content is simple, or you are
> intentionally relying on the default behavior for performance gains.
>
> Since it’s a generic mechanism for Vue to identify nodes, the `key`
> also has other uses that are not specifically tied to `v-for`, as we
> will see later in the guide.
>
> > **Don’t use non-primitive values like objects and arrays as v-for keys.**
> > **Use string or numeric values instead.**
>
> For detailed usage of the `key` attribute, please see the `key` [API
> documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key).

Comment: Could be? So it might not be? So this is just a wild guess?

Comment: usually you should use a unique identifier provided by the objects you iterate over. e.g. server.id. with array keys there could be problems with reactivity when you remove or reorder the elements of the array.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed the same error by adding the **:key** attribute to the  element.

```
<app-server-status v-for="server in 5" :key="server"></app-server-status>
```

It's working fine for me. The duplicating same component displaying 5 times. Hope, It will be helpful to you.

I've got this solution from the https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/858

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after some tinkering with the code I've found that the following code works and doesn't throw an error:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <app-server-status v-for="server in 5" v-bind:key="server"></app-server-status>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ServerStatus from './ServerStatus'

    export default {
        components: {
            'app-server-status': ServerStatus
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: missing the ServerStatus file extension .vue

Answer (score 0):

Sure, key binding is 'recommended' with v-for, but there are instances where I don't need/want it. Adding this clause inside vue.config.js gave me peace in my life again:

```
  module.exports = {
    // this may not be a good option for beginners
    // as it will disable linting.
    lintOnSave: false
  }
```